# Как выровнять текст ошибки вровень с текстом, xml

Tags: android, xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/textinput_container_height"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle"
tools:hint="@string/ip_printers">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
android:digits="1234567890.:"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
android:maxLength="40"
android:maxLines="1"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle"
tools:text="1234567890" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: wrong ip]

Ребята, подскажите, как можно текст ошибки подвинуть к левому краю вровень с текстом выше. Сама ошибка отображается в TextInputLayout.
Задавая отрицательный margin, двигается весь блок, чего мне не нужно.

Comment: Отступы в TextInputLayout - боль. Может быть получится добиться нужного результата сдвинув текст в EditText вправо `padding`-ом?

Comment: Покажите ваш стиль `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle`. Думаю проблема в нём, потому что по умолчанию у errorText нет отступов. И почему ширина у `TextInputLayout` 0dp?

Comment: <style name="ValidationTextInputStyle">
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle</item>
    </style>


<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle">

<item name="android:textColor">@color/text_error</item>

<item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>

</style>

Ширина текста 0dp, т.к. еще кнопку поиска реализовывал справа.